# Unable to dump mysql tables to local

Tags: 14.04, mysql, apparmor

I was trying to dump my mysql table using the below command

```
mysqldump --tab=/home/username/Desktop/basic/ --user myusername -p mysql user;
```

But it returned an error saying

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1: Can't create/write to file '/home/username/Desktop/basic/user.txt' (Errcode: 13) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04. I have tried to disable apparmor as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile). But still the error exists. Any other solutions?

**Edit**

I get the .sql file but not the .txt file

Comment: Have you reload `apparmor` after having made the changes? `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`

Comment: @kos Yes I did. I have tried `restart` also. Still not working.

Comment: I just noticed you didn't specify one database, that's likely the issue. If you want to dump all databases just add the `--all-databases` option

Comment: @kos `mysql` is the database name and `user` is the table name. (Which is the default database in mysql)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the password must follow `-p` right after. Are permissions in such directory correctly set? Try to make `mysql` the owner: `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /home/username/Desktop/basic/ && sudo chmod -R a+rwx /home/username/Desktop/basic/`, also make sure that the expected output file is not already present (i.e. no `user.sql` or `user.txt` files are present before issuing the command)

Comment: @kos Thanks a lot . I made mysql the owner and that worked!! Could you please add that as an answer? May be useful for others facing such issues. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that `mysql` can write to `/home/username/Desktop/basic/`; if you're planning to do multiple dumps in the same directory, a pretty clean way to do it would be to set the ownership of the folder to `mysql` and to set the SGID permission on the folder (thanks to muru for this suggestion): this way `mysqldump` will be able to write to the folder, but new files will inherit the the group from the parent directory; this has the advantage of leaving to your user read, write, and execute permissions on the dumps.

```
sudo chown mysql /home/username/Desktop/basic/ && sudo chmod g+s /home/username/Desktop/basic/
```

Additionally, make sure that there isn't any file named `user.sql` or `user.txt` present in the target directory before issuing the command; if either `mysql` can't write to the target directory or a file with the same name of one of the expected output files exists before issuing the command, `mysqldump` is going to fail.